# Batch Maven Builds with 2 Separate versions

Tags: maven, batch-file, command-line, maven-2, maven-3

I'm trying to build a whole bunch of maven projects in a batch script. There are 2 sets that use (require) different versions of maven. Meaning: half of the projects use Maven 3.1.1 and the other uses 2.2.1, but some of those projects that use maven 2 require some of the maven 3 projects. 
I'm trying to do this all in one script as such:

```
 setx M2 %APACHE%\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\
 rebuildCore
 setx M2 %APACHE%\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\
 rebuildApp
 7z x "%workspace%\win32-app\target\win32-product-0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" -o%Desktop% *.* -r -y > nul
```

The %APACHE% variable points to where the two maven installations are, %Desktop% points to my desktop, and %workspace% is my eclipse workspace.

rebuildCore and rebuildApp are 2 other batch scripts that build my projects, and those work fine.

The problem I am facing is that maven won't change what it points to at runtime after the command prompt has been started, and all windows have to be closed for it to refresh.

Is there any way to completely close all command prompt or powershell windows and run this without starting a new script? I know this seems unlikely, which is why I'm having problems with it.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more in detail why you need to build with different Maven versions? Why does not one version work? And what does it mean 'half of the projects use Maven 3.1.1 and the other uses 2.2.1' ? Does you have limitations according to plugins? Can you show pom excerpts ?

Comment: Sure. What it breaks down to is that the 2.2.1 section is an RCP app that utilizes artifacts from other teams, and that section has not been uplifted to maven 3 yet, and requires maven 2 because of different dependency issues that I am not fully aware of, nor able to specify here. It will be uplifted, but for the next several months, I have to build it with maven 3.
The other section, the ones that build on 3.x require 3.x to build and were relatively recently uplifted to utilize more of maven 3.

Comment: The RCP parts should work with Maven 3 so i don't see the point? What exactly is the problem? Particular plugin?

Comment: Yes. It is one from the company I work with that I can't change. Also, they are old versions of eclipse rcp, which doesn't entirely make it stop working, but we have dependencies and pull in project poms from other teams whose poms do not support maven 3.x by requiring 2.x, so we have to keep certain things back for the moment.

The problem is that I need to switch maven versions. I can't change what version of maven the older projects require and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you use a symlink in your path (e.g. environment variable M2 points to C:\maven\bin; and C:\maven is a symlink pointing to C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-x.x.x), such that you can delete the symlink or NTFS junction in the middle of the script, and recreate it to another version of Maven. Example of how I changed this:

```
cd C:\
rmdir maven
mklink /j maven "%APACHE%\apache-maven-3.2.1"
start /wait cmd /q /c rebuildCore.bat
cd C:\
rmdir maven
mklink /j maven "%APACHE%\apache-maven-2.2.1"
start /wait cmd /q /c rebuildApp
:: THIS LAST LINE EXTRACTS MY RCP APP FROM THE BUILT ZIP FILE TO A FOLDER ON MY DESKTOP
7z x "C:\Users\USER\workspace\app-win32-std-product\target\app-win32-std-product-2.4-SNAPSHOT.zip" -oC:\Users\USER\Desktop\ *.* -r -y
```